# Validating a value from an Excel sheet with text in a webpage

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I want to validate a string that is present in an Excel sheet, with another string present in a web page. When I am trying to do this, it is showing me an error: "Incompatible operand types String and WebElement". Does anyone have any solution?

```
if (s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents()==driver.findElement(By.tagName(s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents()))) {
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to do two things for this:-

First, 
`driver.findElement(By.tagName(s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents()))`

needs to be changed to

`driver.findElement(By.tagName(s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents())).getText()`.

Next, for the `String` comparison, use the `equals()` method.

Hence, your `if` will now look like this:-

```
if (s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents().equals(driver.findElement(By.tagName(s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents())).getText())) {
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

Comment: damn you! You did steal my answer I was about to write :)

+1 for good answer

Comment: Can't really blame me as it was **unanswered** for the past 15 mins :)

Comment: guys i tried your answer, but i still am not able to validate the text present in the page.... its just that the page is not exactly a webpage its a message from the server side... that has to be validated with a text present in the excel sheet... the source code of the page is disabled, basically you will not be able to find any kind of WebElement in that page... but the result opens in a webpage... 

Example
Result code : - "198658" Etc...

Comment: am sorry... am not blaming any one...it was just that i was trying every possible combination using your answer... but every time am hitting a wall... :( is there any other possible way that can be done??

Answer (score 0):

Try this!! either both or one of this combinations will work for you :)

```
if ((s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents()).equals(driver.findElement(By.tagName("***tag name from your site***").getText())) {
    System.out.println("success");
}
```

If this condition fail to work then try to use assertEquals()

```
assertEquals((s1.getCell(0, 0).getContents()), (driver.findElement(By.tagName("***tag name from your site***")).getText()));
System.out.println("success");
```

Thank you

Comment: please tell me if you get errors still; so that I can assist you with alternate solutions.